# how do you create a filter based on grok in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, grok

I am trying to insert this entry to elasticsearch using logstash:

```
2016-05-18 00:14:30,915 DEBUG http-bio-/158.134.18.57-8200-exec-1, HTTPReport - Saved report job 1000 for report
2016-05-18 00:14:30,937 DEBUG http-bio-/158.134.18.57-8200-exec-1, JavaReport - 
************************************************************************************************
Report Job information
Job ID : 12000
Job name : 101
Job priority : 1
Job group : BACKGROUND
Report : Month End
2016-05-18 00:17:38,868 DEBUG JobsMaintenanceScheduler_Worker-1, DailyReport - System information: available processors = 12; memory status : 2638 MB of 4096 MB
```

I have this filter in the logstash conf file:

```
        input {
  file {
    path => "/data/*.log"
    type => "app_log"
    start_position => "beginning"
  }
}

filter {

      multiline {
                pattern => "(([\s]+)20[0-9]{2}-)|20[0-9]{2}-"
                negate => true
                what => "previous"
                }

  if [type] == "app_log" {
    grok {
                patterns_dir => ["/pattern"]
                match => {"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp},%{NUMBER:Num_field} %{WORD:error_level} %{GREEDYDATA:origin}, %{WORD:logger} - %{GREEDYDATA:event%}"}
        }
    }

     mutate { add_field => {"type" => "app_log"}}
     mutate { add_field => {"machine_name" => "server101"}}
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts=> "localhost:9200"
    index => "app_log-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
    manage_template => false
  }
}
```

I am getting this error:

```
translation missing: en.logstash.runner.configuration.file-not-found {:level=>:error}
```

Not able to insert it. Any ideas what might be wrong?

Comment: Which version of Logstash are you running? Also note that your `grok/match` property is missing `"}` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to the latest version of Logstash (= 2.3.2), fix your grok filter like below and it will work:

```
 grok {
       add_field => {"machine_name" =>"server010"}
       match =>{"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp} %{WORD:error_level} %{DATA:origin}, %{DATA:logger_name} - %{GREEDYDATA:EVENT}"}
 }
```

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: after trying this, I should have fields like machine_name, timestamp, error_level key value pair, right?

Comment: I tried that I dont see machine_name, error_level, also what about the comma in the message?

Comment: The comma is not a problem. If you try my grok pattern [on this page](http://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/), you'll see that it can parse your log line correctly.

Comment: not able to pick this up "pool-383-thread-1", what do thing would be the type here, it is not I tried DATA and WORD, no sucess

Comment: Make sure to remove the space + backslash before the comma.

Comment: I got it. One other question I have. I have a logstash instance and I'll be manually placing file to a directory from bunch of servers and placing it in logstash directory called /data. How would I update the machine_name variable? Would it be possible to extract it from the file name the logstash reading at the time. For example if the file name is this server101_apache.log, how could I update the machine_name to server101?

Comment: I suggest we close this question and you create another one since this is a different issue. For the benefit of readers landing on this question in the future ;)

Comment: would you be able to look at this post/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37551000/unable-to-re-process-the-log-file-using-logstash-version-2-3-2

Comment: I accepted your answer, but actually it is not working. I am not able to see custome fields like machine_name, eror_level etc in elasticsearch.

Comment: Add an `stdout {}` output so we can see what gets sent to elasticsearch.

Comment: also, when remove the index and data from elastic search and trying to log the same log message, it is not going in. I'm remoging any .send data, still no luck. Any ideas?

Comment: I've updated post. Each line should should start with a timestamp. The conf file I've posted not working, I still see entries in ES where it does not start with timestamp. Sorry for all these questions, as you can see, I am very new to this.

Comment: Well, the second log line you've added is not really the same as the original one anymore, hence why it's not working.

Comment: Also you check for `type=erp_log` but your input is creating `type:app_log`, hence your grok is never triggered.

Comment: other then the type issue, do you see any other issue?

Comment: You should start with that one and then we'll see if there's another one.

Comment: I just changed it, not working. Each line should start with timestamp, if not, entries does not start with the timestamp, should be part of the previous line that starts with entries. This syntax is not working,

Comment: As I said previously, the new log lines you've added are really different than the original ones, since you now need proper multiline handling.

Comment: I have a multiline handling in there

Comment: Are you certain that it works? You seem to be expecting a space (i.e. `[\s]+`) as the first character, but that's not the case in the log lines you're showing.

Comment: yes, you're right. How can I change this so that it checks for timestamps, if not merge it with the previous line?

Comment: This deviates quite a bit from the original question. I think it would be better if you create a brand new question with this new requirement. What do you say? Just to keep this thread friendly for people tackling it.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check your next question.