# how do you parse text in grok

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I need to capture two variables from this path using grok:

```
/opt/data/app_log/server101.log

server=needs to be anything after the last forward slash before the dot (in this case server101)
index=needs to be the text between the last two forward slashes (in this case app_log)
```

Any ideas how could do this in grok?

```
 grok {
                patterns_dir => ["/pattern"]
                match =>{path =>"%{WORD:dir1}\/%{WORD:dir2}\/%{WORD:index_name}\/%{WORD:server}\.%{WORD:file_type}"}
                match => {"message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp},%{NUMBER:Num_field} %{WORD:error_level} %{GREEDYDATA:origin}, %{WORD:logger} - %{GREEDYDATA:message}"}
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest solution is

```
/%{DATA:col1}/%{DATA:col2}/%{DATA:index}/%{DATA:server}\.%{GREEDYDATA:end}
```

you can remove the names `col1`, `col2`, and `end` to drop those captures.

This pattern relies on there always being the same number of parts in your URI. If there are a variable number you could use something like this.

```
(?:/%{USER})*/%{DATA:index}/%{DATA:server}\.%{GREEDYDATA:end}
```

I made and tested these using [the grok constructor](http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match)

---

Using this pattern:

```
filter {
  grok {
    match => { 
      "message" => <message-pattern>
    }
  }
  grok {
    match => { 
      "log_path" => "(?:/%{USER})*/%{DATA:index}/%{DATA:server}\.%{GREEDYDATA}"
    }
  }
}
```

Where `"log_path"` is the name of the field containing the log path after you do your normal message parsing.

Comment: I need to parse the log file to, would I be able to include two match under one grok, like the one I modified in the original post? If I do that, I am am not able to see the fields parsed from the message in my ES instances.

Comment: You can have a grok filter that parses the log and a grok filter that uses this pattern on the field that contains the path string

Comment: two different grok or within one grok as it shown above? If I do it as above, I dont see the custom field I try to extract from the log file.